# Creating pages when activating plugin WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Anyone Please help!
I have a plugin which creates post_type pages in the backend. The plugin is creating the desired pages but the problem is whenever i try to see the page list, it shows "No pages found" message. Screenshot here: http://prnt.sc/azalub

My code for creating the required pages here:

```
$new_page = array('post_title'    => $title,
                  'post_content'  => '['.$shortcode.']',
                  'post_status'   => 'publish',
                  'post_type'     => 'page'
                );
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_page );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a custom post type, i had set 'query_var' to 'true' on one of the custom post type in my plugin. Setting it 'false' just made everything fine.

Answer (score 16):

For this purpose, you need to register with plugin activation [hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).
See the code example below:

```
function add_my_custom_page() {
    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'My Custom Page' ),
      'post_content'  => 'My custom page content',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_my_custom_page');
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion but still no help. I have used OOP approach in my plugin where i have hooked that function in the register_activation.

Comment: on my screenshot  working fine. you can see above image... You can try as create new plugin without any other code and add my code to working or not ...if getting any problem info me i will help out..

Comment: I have used same code in my previous plugin and it is working fine. But just can't figure out this one. Upon de-activating plugin, it looks just fine. But on activation, the error comes back.

Comment: opps.. you can share your code with me. i will check it and solved.

Comment: I fixed it myself. It was 'query_var' which was set true on one of my CPT. I just set it false and it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using class try pass `array($this, 'method_name')` instead of function name.